# Repeat command with interval in redis intaractive mode

Tags: redis

How can I set interval when repeating command several time in the interactive mode?

Like when I using redis-cli:

```
redis-cli -r 10 -i 1 PING
```

In interactive mode I can set amount of repeats before the command:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> 10 PING
```

But how can I set interval here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start redis-cli with the `-i interval` option:

```
redis-cli -i 2
127.0.0.1:6379> 2 PING
```

However, in this case, all command will delay `interval` seconds, even if you don't want to repeat the command.

Comment: So no chances to set an interval per command in the interactive mode directly?

Comment: AFAIK, you CANNOT do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
for i in {1..10}; do redis-cli ping ; echo "running for $i th time"; sleep $i; done;
```